# Putting a table in a 2d array and display it

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have 2 questions , please help me.

1. In PHP/MySQL I have a long query that I write it in 7 lines . now I
   want to  run it and put a result of that query (a table ) as a 2d
   array in a variable . how can I do it ?
2. After I put result of query as a 2d array in the a variable , now
   how can I display the result of my query in the form of table in the
   html page ?

thanks

****** Example **************

```
        $database_host = "localhost";
    $database_username = "root";
    $database_password = ""; // FOR ME!!!   

    $connection = mysql_connect("$database_host", "$database_username", "$database_password") or die("Could't connect to database!");
    if(!mysql_select_db("football_db", $connection)) 
        die("Could't select database!");

    // Sanitizing leagueName input
    $leagueName = strtolower(strval($_POST[ 'leagueName' ])); 
    $leagueName = stripslashes( $leagueName ); 

    // Sanitizing seasonName input
    $seasonName = strtolower(strval($_POST[ 'seasonName' ])); 
    $seasonName = stripslashes( $seasonName ); 



    $query = "SELECT cl.club_name , cr.played , cr.matches_won AS W , cr.matches_lose AS L , 
        (cr.played - ( cr.matches_won + cr.matches_lose) ) AS D , 
        cr.goals_for AS GF , cr.goals_against AS GA , (cr.goals_for - cr.goals_against) AS GD ,
        (cr.matches_won*3 + (cr.played - ( cr.matches_won + cr.matches_lose) ) ) AS PTS
    FROM ClubsRecords AS cr , Clubs AS cl , Seasons AS se , leagues AS le
    WHERE le.league_type='$leagueName' AND  se.season_name ='$seasonName' AND 
        se.league_id = le.league_id AND cr.club_id = cl.club_id AND cr.season_id = se.season_id 
    ORDER BY PTS DESC;";
```

Comment: Yes, I googled it but I didn't know how can I put the result of query in a 2d array and display it.

Comment: Anyway if we are to help you we need data example, this question is just too general.

Comment: @amiramir you can use `json_encode()` for solve this easily.

Comment: I put my problem in the post.

Comment: @amiramir please add output from `print_r( mysql_fetch_Assoc( $query))` and example for required data if Afir's answer isn't good.

Comment: you want to save it directly through mysql?

Comment: Putting variables into your SQL means you now are vulnerable to hacking via SQL Injection, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

I think this can help you.

Comment: thanks for your great help but I want to display that 2d array like a table in a html page. with "json_encode" , it displays the result of query like a set not table.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Question 1: */

    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // $rows is your 2d-array

/* Question 2: */

    echo "<table>\n";

    // print the rownames
    $keys = array_keys($rows);
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        echo "    <td>$key</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";

// print the values
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    print('<tr>');
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        echo "    <td>$value</td>\n";
        }
    print('</tr>');
}
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Your second answer didn't display 2d array as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb with an obvious answer without really knowing what kind of two dimensional array you're looking for:

```
$twoDimArray = array();
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result !== false)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $twoDimArray[] = $row;
    }
}
```